# jquery/mysql remove item from selectbox if selected

Tags: jquery, mysql

Scenario:

I have problem to fill the new select box when user click add button. 
if I select a user and click the add button it automatically removes from the select box.

I have two tables:
Users
Courses

```
<select name="user" id="user">
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">Doe</option>
    <option value="3">Fred</option>
    <option value="4">Mann</option> 
</select>
```

**Courses**

Math

if I click add:

John
Doe

The select box remains

```
<option value="3">Fred</option>
<option value="4">Mann</option>
```

Accounting

if I click add:

John
Fred

The select box remain

```
<option value="2">Doe</option>
<option value="4">Mann</option>
```

Ive tried this query

```
SELECT `courses`.`userNumber` FROM `courses` 
left join user ON user.`userNumber` = `courses`.`userNumber`
WHERE `SchedcourseID` = 2
```

the result of this all user who was registered on the courses.

What I need all user that is not register on this courses.

Comment: And where is the jQuery MySQL code?

Comment: Im thinking if its posible to use mysql query for this.. like using not in.. but i didnt get the result that i expected

Comment: Okay, but can you show us what you tried? We are not going to post a whole code doing that, but we will surely help you fix your code

Comment: Ive tried this query

SELECT `courses`.`userNumber` FROM `courses` 
left join user ON user.`userNumber` = `courses`.`userNumber`
WHERE `SchedcourseID` = 2
the result of this all user who was registered on the courses.

What I need all user that is not register on this courses.

Comment: I have search similar to this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7c60/15